# List Branches With Active Choices Using Groovy Script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to list github branches for a parameterized Jenkins job using active choice plugin. I tried the following groovy scripts, but to no avail - no branch is retrieved/listed on the drop down.

1.

```
def process = ("ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa; git ls-remote -t -h git@github.com:username/repository.git'").execute()
return process.text.readLines().collect { 
  it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

2.

```
def command = 'ssh-add /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa; git ls-remote -t -h git@github.com:username/repository.git'
def process = ["ssh-agent", "bash", "-c", command].execute()
return process.text.readLines().collect { 
  it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

3.

```
def process = ["ssh-agent", "bash", "-c", "ssh-add", "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa", "git", "ls-remote", "-t", "-h", "git@github.com:username/repository.git"].execute()
return process.text.readLines().collect { 
  it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

I suspect this has something to do with how groovy parses nested shell commands, but I am not sure.

Your help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I tried script 2 in groovysh as suggested by @cfrick and it works perfectly fine. It seems that the issue has something to do with my Jenkins version because extensible choice parameter plugin is having the same issue with my groovy script.

I decided to do a work around for my needs and dropped this whole thing.

Comment: "but to no avail" - what does that mean? Please add the errors you get (stacktraces, logs, ...) or how the result differs from what you expect.

Comment: @cfrick I edited the question. There are no branches retrieved.

Comment: Try it in a `groovysh` and debug from there.  I am pretty sure that 1 and 3 will never work - 2 at least looks somewhat correct (around the parameters with `bash -c`)

Comment: @cfrick Thanks. I will update the question if I find something and need help.